# else IndentationError: unexpected unindent in PyCharm

Tags: python, mysql

Error in PyCharm:

```
File "Biblio.py", line 96
    else:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

Today I added some mores lines of code, but when i run it it throw out above  error.
Checked blank spaces and tabs but nothing.
Also if i add others elses, for example for the "if alum_desc >= 1 and alum_desc <= 3:" its also gives me the same error. So dont know why this is happening.

```
import mysql.connector
db = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='biblio', passwd='bablio', db='Biblioteca', unix_socket='/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock')
cursor = db.cursor()
print("Hola, ha accedido al programa de Gestión de la Biblioteca de AQUI")

is_rg = int(input("Desea: 1-Iniciar Sesion / 2-Registrarse"))
cl_rg = 'melocoton'
if is_rg == 1 :
    user = input("Usuario: ")
    pasw = input("Contraseña: ")
    try:
        cursor.execute("SELECT Nombre, Usuario, Contraseña, Rango FROM Personas WHERE Usuario='%s'" %(user) )
        for Nombre, Usuario, Contraseña, Rango in cursor:
            names = Nombre
            pasws = Contraseña
            users = Usuario
            rangooo = Rango
        if (users == user) and (pasws == pasw):
            print("Sesion Iniciada con éxito")
            ses_in = 1

        else:
            if pasws != pasw:
                print("contraseña incorrecta")
            else:
                print("error inesperado")
    except:
        print("No se ha encontrado ninugn usuario")
    if ses_in == 1:
        if rangooo == profesor:
            print("Nyaaa Senseiiii")
            print("Notificaciones:")
            cursor.execute("SELECT ")
        else:
            print("Hola Alumno ", names)
            try:
                cursor.execute("SELECT Libro, Dias FROM Libros WHERE Nombre= '%s'" %(names) )
                for Libro, Dias in cursor:
                    print("Tiene el Libro: ", Libro, " , y le faltan ", Dias, " para devolverlo")
                cogido = 1
            except:
                print("Actualmente no tiene ningun libro")
                cogido = 0
            if cogido == 0:
                print("Desea:")
                print("1-ver los libros disponibles y coger uno")
                print("2-Coger un Libro")
                print("3-Volver al menu")

                alum_desc = input("Deseo: ")
                if alum_desc >= 1 and alum_desc <= 3:
                    if alum_desc == 1:
                        print("1- ver todos los libros disponibles y no disponibles")
                        print("2- buscar libros por generos")
                        tod_gen = input("Desea ver todos los libros disponibles y no disponibles")
                        if tod_gen >= 1 and alum_desc <= 2:
                            if tod_gen == 1:
                                cursor.execute("SELECT id, Libro, Genero  FROM Libros WHERE Dias= 'x' " )
                                for id, Libro, Genero in cursor:
                                    print("Los siguientes libros estan disponibles")
                                    print(id, Libro, Genero)
                                cursor.execute("SELECT id, Libro, Genero, Dias FROM Libros WHERE Dias!= 'x'")
                                for Libro,Genero,Dias in cursor:
                                    print("Los siguientes libros estaran disponibles en")
                                    print(Libro,"   ",Genero,"   Estara disponible en: ",Dias)
                            if tod_gen == 2:
                                dec_gen = input("1-Fantasia 2-Ficcion 3-Terror")
                                if dec_gen >= 1 and dec_gen <= 3:
                                    if dec_gen == 1:
                                        gen_sel = 'Fantasia'
                                    if dec_gen == 2:
                                        gen_sel = 'Ficcion'
                                    if dec_gen == 3:
                                        gen_sel = 'Terror'
                                else:
                                    print("Eliga una opcion correcta")
                                cursor.execute("SELECT id, Libro, Genero, Dias FROM Libros WHERE Dias= 'x' AND Genero= dec_gen ")
                                for id, Libro, Genero in cursor:
                                    print("Los siguientes libros del genero ", dec_gen, "estan disponibles")
                                    print(id, Libro)
                                cursor.execute("SELECT id, Libro, Genero, Dias FROM Libros WHERE Dias!= 'x' AND Genero= dec_gen ")
                                for Libro,Genero,Dias in cursor:
                                    print("Los siguientes libros del genero: ",dec_gen, "estaran disponibles en")
                                    print(Libro,"   Estara disponible en: ",Dias)


                        else:
                            print("Introduzca una opcion correcta")
                    if alum_desc == 2:
                        id_lib = input("Introduzca el id del libro que desea coger")
                        try:
                            cursor.execute("UPDATE Libros SET Nombre='%s',Dias='%s',Notificacion='%s' WHERE id='%s'" %(names,'15','si',id_lib))
                            db.commit()
                            print("Ha cogido el libro con exito")

else:
    if is_rg == 2:
        print("Registración, recuerda que debes contar con la clave para registrarse")
        cl_p = input("Inserte la calve de registro"))
        if cl_p == cl_rg:
            print("La clave de registro es correcta, puede proceder a registrarse")
            nombre_nuevo = input("Indique su nombre:")
            ususario_nuevo = input("Escriba el nombre de Usuario que le gustaria tener")
            try:
                cursor.execute("SELECT Nombre FROM Personas WHERE Nombre='%s'" %(usuario_nuevo) )
                print("Lo siento ese usuario ya existe, piense en otro")
            except:
                contra_nueva = input("Eliga su contraseña")


            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Personas (Nombre, Usuario, Contraseña) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')" %(nombre_nuevo, ususario_nuevo, contra_nueva) )
            db.commit()
            print("Se ha registrado con éxito")

    else:
        print("Eliga una opcion correcta")
```

Comment: you should missed one `except` clause at line#=95.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE Libros SET Nombre='%s',Dias='%s',Notificacion='%s' WHERE id='%s'" %(names,'15','si',id_lib))
    db.commit()
    print("Ha cogido el libro con exito")
```

Over here you have a try but no except. Add a

```
except Exception:
    pass
```

:)

Comment: Yeah realized it cheking again. Ty for you help